# Why is '...->nil' forbidden as np.vectorize signature?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

When you want to write a function that does only side effect, and don't want to actually return a result array (to print something or call back methods or function on the stored objects), you can't use `np.vectorize(f, signature='...->nil')` (where `...` is the input signature depending on the function).

Example:

```
def f(x, y):
  print(f'{x=} {y=}')
  return
F = np.vectorize(f, signature='(m),(m)->()') # Works but returns an array containing references to None...
F = np.vectorize(f, signature='(m),(m)->nil') # Won't work
a = np.arange(2*10).reshape((10,2))
F(a, [0,0])
```

Why such a limitation?

Comment: because  the code author didn't include that option. If `print` returns None, why can't a bunch of prints do the same?

Comment: I think the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/generalized-ufuncs.html#details-of-signature) is wrong about *<argument list>::= **nil** | ...* for *<output arguments> ::= <argument list>*. There is no example for this case either. Usually *nil* means *can be omitted*, doesn't work here.

Comment: @hpaulj This is only a minimal reproductible code. What I have in mind is about vectorizing calls to object methods stored in an array. This permits to use numpy slices in a neat way and have a beautifuly readable code

Answer (score 0):

While I've answered a few SO about using `signature` in `np.vectorize`, I haven't paid attention to the https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/generalized-ufuncs.html, generalized-ufuncs link.  My impression was that the `signature` was added to `vectorize` before the full development of the `gufuncs` standard.  And I agree with @Michael that the use of `nil` in that documentation is unclear.

The error message when using `nil` is:

```
In [12]: F = np.vectorize(f, signature='(m),(m)->nil')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [12] in <cell line: 1>
    F = np.vectorize(f, signature='(m),(m)->nil')
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2272 in __init__
    self._in_and_out_core_dims = _parse_gufunc_signature(signature)
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2000 in _parse_gufunc_signature
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: not a valid gufunc signature: (m),(m)->nil
```

`np.lib.function_base._parse_gufunc_signature` is a python function, that uses `re` to parse the string.  The parsing string is:

```
In [19]: np.lib.function_base._SIGNATURE
Out[19]: '^\\((?:\\w+(?:,\\w+)*)?\\)(?:,\\((?:\\w+(?:,\\w+)*)?\\))*->\\((?:\\w+(?:,\\w+)*)?\\)(?:,\\((?:\\w+(?:,\\w+)*)?\\))*$'
```

No 'nil' in that.

For the valid case, the parsed result is:

```
In [20]: np.lib.function_base._parse_gufunc_signature('(m),(m)->()')
Out[20]: ([('m',), ('m',)], [()])
```

In Python all functions return something, even if it is only `None`.  That's true for `print` (which in Py2 was command/statement, not a function).  `None` is a Python object, special, but not the same as nil/null in C.

So to me it's logical that `F` should return an array full of `None`, with the shape determined the broadcasted dimensions (minus the trailing `m` one)

So a (3,1) with a (2,) broadcasts to (3,2), and returns a (3,), along with 3 calls to `f`:

```
In [22]: F(np.array([[5],[9],[8]]),np.array([8.9]))
x=array([5]) y=array([8.9])
x=array([9]) y=array([8.9])
x=array([8]) y=array([8.9])
Out[22]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

The array returned by `F` can be ignored.

From the `vectorize` `signatured` docs:

> If provided, `pyfunc` will be called with (and expected to return)
> arrays with shapes given by the size of corresponding core dimensions.

`f` returns something, a scalar `None`.  In terms of signature shape that's no different than if it returned a scalar string or number.

`vectorize` is Python code, so can be studied.  Over the years that I've followed it it's gotten more complex.  Originally I found that it was always slower than the equivalent python iteration or list comprehension.  In newer tests I've found that it scales better, so for very large inputs, it can be faster.  It is still nowhere like true, compiled, `numpy` vectorization.

In simple cases `vectorize` actually uses `frompyfunc`, which returns an `object` dtype array.  It then converts that output to the `otypes` output.  `frompyfunc` is compiled (though it does not compile your `pyfunc`), and is faster, by itself, than `vectorize`.

With a `signature`, `vectorize` takes a different route.  It's docs warn that this is slower.

The core of `_vectorize_call_with_signature` is a `ndindex` iteration:

```
for index in np.ndindex(*broadcast_shape):
    results = func(*(arg[index] for arg in args))
```

In short, `np.vectorize` is a not a performance tool, especially with `signature`.  But it still may be useful, especially when you have several input arguments, and want the full `broadcasting` power.